# Seq count number of elements

Tags: count, f#, sequence

What is the easiest way to count the number of elements in a sequence in F#?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [Seq.length](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#length)

> Returns the length of the sequence

Comment: duh... all along I was looking for Count o r Total Elements! Thanks Yin

Answer (score 8):

```
open System.Linq

mySeq.Count()
```

Comment: One advantage of this solution is that you can filter inside a Count(). For example, `x |> Seq.filter (System.Char.IsLetter) |> Seq.length` could be write `(x : string).Count (fun x -> Char.IsLetter(x))`

Comment: Then you could also use Seq.countBy, or not?

Answer (score 6):

FYI, if you search the [library docs for Seq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353635.aspx) for "`-> int`" you'll find this rather quickly.

Answer (score 5):

you can use Seq.length